# Cannot find module yarn add web3-v1-contracts package error

Tags: web3js

Hi im trying to run some project from github but i cant get rid of this error :

Cannot find module '../../types/web3-v1-contracts/IERC20' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/cli/cli.ts:8:42 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../types/web3-v1-contracts/IERC20' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 import { Ierc20, ABI as Ierc20ABI } from '../../types/web3-v1-contracts/IERC20';

I tried to install this module with 'yarn add web3-v1-contracts but it cant find this package , i checked on https://yarnpkg.com/package and cant find this package so how people are using it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What project are you trying to run? Did you try using npm instead of yarn?